# bing map, stop from scrolling the map wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am a newbie to windows phone. Using vs2010 and os 7.1 I have a map containing a layer, what I want to do is drag the layer around but it only happens if am dragging the layer real slow, if I try move it just even a little bit faster, map starts scrolling instead of that layer being dragged.So, in short I want to disable the map scroll while I am clicking/holding/dragging that layer. I just need to know what property or what I need to disable for the map to stop scrolling.I have googled it alot, but to no avail.I would appreciate it alot if you could tell me the solution in c#(preferably). Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.
Here is the xaml code:

```
 <my:Map x:Name="MyMap" CredentialsProvider="my_key" MouseLeftButtonUp="map_onMouseLeftButtonUp" Mode="AerialWithLabels">
                <my:MapLayer x:Name="mylayer" Hold="mouseHoldingMapLayer" MouseMove="MouseMoveOverMapLayer" ></my:MapLayer></my:Map>
```

Note: I have only tried it on emulator. Don't have a device to test on.
Edit : Also neither`MyMap.IsEnabled = false;` nor `MyMap.IsHitTestVisible =false;` works. Both disable the user interaction with map as well as with child(layer in this case) and explicitly setting `mylayer.IsHitTestVisible =true;` doesn't not work either. As said in documentation of isHitTestVisible under the reference section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx

Comment: I don't know the wp7 API so you are gonna have to do some digging, but perhaps you can go with the idea of overriding the default map drag handler to do nothing while your layer is being moved, and restoring it after your layer is done moving.

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure how to do that. As I said I am just a beginner. Thanks for your reply. I will try and look into your suggestion and post back here if I find something.